# Python don't return data when joining two tables by a field

Tags: python, mysql

I've got a query that returns the data correctly in MySQL but in Python only returns part of the data.

The query is:

```
select sc.* from tbl030_shots_chart sc, tbl006_player_team tc where
sc.id_fiba = tc.id_player_feb and
tc.id_team_club = 5
```

This query in MySQL returns 1030 rows like you can see in this screen cap.

[image]

However, If I execute this query with python, I've got only 67 rows. This is my code:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_HOST,
                      user = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_USER,
                      password = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_PSWD,
                      db = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_NAME,
                      charset = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_CHARSET,
                      cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    totalRows = cursor.execute("select sc.* from tbl030_shots_chart sc, tbl006_player_team tc where sc.id_fiba = tc.id_player_feb and tc.id_team_club = %s", [5])
    print("Total Rows: " + str(totalRows))
```

And this is the exit:

[image]

Why I've got les data from Python than MySQL?

These are the definition of the tables:

*tbl030_shots_chart*
[image]

*tbl006_player_team* 
[image]

**Edit I:**

With inner join doesn't work in python but works in MySQL

[image]

However, with python, still returns 76 rows and not 1030 like MySQL.

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_HOST,
                      user = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_USER,
                      password = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_PSWD,
                      db = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_NAME,
                      charset = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_CHARSET,
                      cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    totalRows = cursor.execute("select sc.* from tbl030_shots_chart as sc inner join tbl006_player_team as pt on sc.id_fiba = pt.id_player_feb and pt.id_team_club = %s", [5])
    print("Total Rows: " + str(totalRows))
```

[image]

If I've got the total rows from the cursor with this code:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_HOST,
                      user = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_USER,
                      password = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_PSWD,
                      db = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_NAME,
                      charset = DDBB.DDBB_FIBA_CHARSET,
                      cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("select sc.* from tbl030_shots_chart as sc inner join tbl006_player_team as pt on sc.id_fiba = pt.id_player_feb and pt.id_team_club = %s", [5])
    totalRows = cursor.rowcount
    print("Total Rows: " + str(totalRows))
```

I've got 76 rows returned and not 1030.

[image]

Comment: how come you're not using a join here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a [view](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html) for this query.

```
CREATE VIEW your_view AS (

    SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.id_game,
    t1.line,
    ...

    t2.id_team_club,
    t2.id_player_feb,
    ...

    FROM tbl030_shots_chart t1
    LEFT JOIN
    tbl006_player_team t2
)
```

Then in your python code:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM your_view WHERE id_fiba =id_player_feb AND id_team_club = %s'
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql, (5))
```

Comment: Hi @Jane!!! But, my problem is with Python not MySQL. Sorry, but I don't understand what do you want :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the cursor `rowcount` attribute:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("select sc.* from tbl030_shots_chart sc, tbl006_player_team tc where sc.id_fiba = tc.id_player_feb and tc.id_team_club = %s", [5])
    totalRows=cursor.rowcount
    print("Total Rows: " + str(totalRows))
```

In the `.execute` method there are no return values defined, so you can get anything.

Comment: I've got the same result, Python returns me 76 rows and not 1030.